# Could asking feedback from competing app's users be considered as unfair competition that could result in legal consequences?

Tags: intellectual-property

I developed a chat app. I wanted to develop a good chat app and wanted a perspective from users. But I kind of stepped over the line and asked users of competing app for feedback. I went to their public group chat room on the app and asked users questions on how that app could be improved. I got various feedback about how they should have a 'like' button, GIF, threading, and etc. I decided to add a like button and comment section for social posting. I asked questions to users several times for two weeks. Then the developer of the app intervened and asked me not to do that. Even though the feedback was given in the public chat room and feedback was a good idea but not a game-changer, could this be an example of misappropriation due to the fact the info was obtained from their app? Could the developer also accuse me of unfair competition to Apple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not "unfair competition". You are allowed to ask people for their views and take them into account in designing software, even with the specific intent that it compete successfully with existing software. In the US you have a protected right to do that under the First Amendment.

If the chat site where you asked is run by the developer or owners of the app, they can ask you to avoid such question there, and even ban you from the site if they choose, because it is their site. But if you went onto a public site (like Stack Exchange, say, or Quora) the app owners would have no right to insist that you not ask for such opinions.

The degree to which the design or interface of an app or other software may be protected against imitation is a complex one, and depends on the country involved. But widely known and used features such as a 'like' button, message threading, or a comment section are almost surely not protectable. Listening to users of existing simile products and getting their ideas on what works well and what is lacking is generally a good idea, and is in no way "unfair".